# PHP Code to open Outlook and send email

Tags: php, linux, email, outlook, send

Is it possible to open Outlook from local system using php inorder to send email from a specific email account. The PHP is hosted in Linux server and I'm not sure whether it is possible. Please help

Comment: The `mailto://` protocol scheme allows to _suggest_ to the client to open an email composer window, you can also append some additional arguments like subject. But you cannot _force_ the client and especially... there has to be some email client program installed and configured at all on the client system. Also you obviously cannot control _which_ email client is used, but the client system will decide that. So in general the answer is: this is not a good idea, it will only work for some users, others will be frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a link like this:

```
<a href="mailto:admin@mysite.com">Send me a mail</a>
```

Which will open the users **default** email program when clicked, with the recipient prefilled with 'admin@mysite.com'.